# vb.net WebView2 and document.evaluate

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, web-scraping, webview2

I'am triying to get the value of a DIV with the full XPath using WebView2 and document.evaluate but I can't find the way to do this.

I have read many things and I assume that I need something like this :

```
Dim path As String = "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div"
WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.evaluate(path, document, Null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, NULL)")
```

but I was not abble to get some functional code.

Any help please ?

Comment: Javscript is case sensitive: Use `null` instead of NULL.

Comment: Also you will have to use `await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync` - otherwise you won't get the result.

Answer (score 0):

@ Poul Bak : Thank you, now I can run the program but the DateStr string remains to null

Here is my new code :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "my url here"
    WebView21.Source = New Uri(URL, False)

    Timer1.Interval = 25000 '25s
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    GetPageInfoAsync()
End Sub

Private Async Function GetPageInfoAsync() As Task

    Dim DateStr As String
    Dim path As String = "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div"

    DateStr = Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)")


End Function
```

Any idea what could be wrong ?

**Edit :**

Now this is an answer. :-)

I foud a very simple solution on this forum :

```
DateStr = Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
```

I can now search in the string the data I need.I will try to search the data using xpath.

**EDIT :**

Sorry, this solution does not work. I am disheartened.

Using the webview allows to wait 25s for the web page to be rendered. But in the rendered web page there is a DIV with only two lines visible and a scrolling to see the other lines.
Unfortunately the code :

```
DateStr = Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
```

only returns the visible elements. The invisible lines of the DIV with scrolling are not in the string.

If someone has a solution, I have to open a web page, wait 25s in order the page to rendered and then acces some DIV data using Xpath like this :
/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div

Thanks !

Comment: The whole thing looks very fragile to me. If the html changes a tiny bit, the xpath will be wrong.

Comment: By the way, you should EDIT your question, when you want give more info, this is NOT an answer!

Comment: @Poul Bak Thank you. Sorry that I have posted an answer. I was not aware about this.